# How to move to sibling in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code in html. and I want to go to a sibling node.
I search by title (since this is a unique value in the UI), but I want to move to the same level but with different class name that will contains ant-select-tree-switcher_close.

This is the xpath to what is marked, and I just want to move in the same level for the first span, but without span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMdPi.png), or any hard coded solution. I want to search by class name that contains the words ant-select-tree-switcher_close  as some text in the class name.

the xpath is:
//*[@title='Arts/Ent']  this is marked in yellow
I want to go to the purple section regards

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preceding-sibling`

```
//*[@title='Arts/Ent']/preceding-sibling::*[contains(@class, 'ant-select-tree-switcher_close')]
```

If you want to use the `'Arts/Ent'` WebElement to locate the sibling you can use

```
./preceding-sibling::*[contains(@class, 'a')]
```